# How can I correctly document instance members added via Object.defineProperties?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I have a class which defines a few instance properties via `Object.defineProperties` and I'm having great difficulty getting [JSDoc 3](https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc) to recognize that they belong to their class.

Here's a simplified version of what I'm working with:

```
/** @exports mymodule */
function mymodule(exports) {
    /** @constructor
      * @param {String} foo A foo.
      * @param {String} bar A bar.
      * @classdesc Has a foo and a bar.
      */
    function Example(foo, bar) {
        Object.defineProperties(this, {
            /** A foo and a bar
              * @memberof Example
              */
            foobar: { enumerable: false, value: foo + bar, writable: false }
        });
    }

    exports.Example = Example;
}
```

When I run JSDoc, I get output for `mymodule`, `Example`, `foo`, and `bar`, but not `foobar`.  If I remove the `@memberof` tag for `foobar`, it get registered as a global.  I've tried `@memberof mymmodule~Example`, adding `@lends` to both the `Object.defineProperties` call and the object passed to it, and converting it to `Object.defineProperty`, but the results don't change.

How can I document `foobar` as belonging to `Example`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After digging through every example I could find, I finally assembled the necessary incantation — `@memberof` is indeed the trick, but JSDoc seems to require that modules being used in namepaths be explicitly marked as such.  The following worked perfectly:

```
/** A foo and a bar
  *
  * @type String
  * @instance
  * @memberof module:mymodule~Example
  */
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try the @lends annotation in place of @memberOf like this :

```
Object.defineProperties(this, /** @lends Example# */{
    /** A foo and a bar */
    foobar: { enumerable: false, value: foo + bar, writable: false }
});
```

Don't forget the sharp symbol after the class name to tell jsdoc members are instance members and not static members.

Answer (score 0):

After fiddling around for many hours, I finally got it to work with `@memberOf!`. Note the uppercase "O" and the bang "!"

```
/**
 * Description
 * @memberOf! MyClass
 * @type {String}
 */
var myString;
```

Comment: Can you give a more verbose example of where this goes in the code? I can't seem to get it to work anywhere.

Comment: I recently switched to JSDuck and it has been some time. Depending on what you want to achieve - in my case this statement had to be everywhere, that is above every variable/property and function/method of an object.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to use `defineProperty` instead, a `@type` annotation is sufficient (at least for IntelliJ to infer the proper type for the property):

```
/** @type SomeType */
Object.defineProperty(this, "someProperty", {
    get: () => new SomeType()
});
```